# Skips animation for custom card stack view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, android-custom-view

So my goal was to do this (do not look at disfigured layouts, i just removed logos):

[sing in card photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu1d1.png)

On click "Sign up" sign in card slides down to screen and registration card goes from the bottom:

[register card photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddCrQ.png)

3 card (all cards are custom View) on second poto have almost same layouts and each sliding down on click "Continue" button

**Issue**

Sliding animation from sign in card to registration skips. Sing in card slides down perfectly but then start delay in ~1 sec and registration card skips sliding in animation and just appears. Animation from registration to sing in card works correct on both cards though.

**Question**

How to solve problem with skipping animation from sing in card to registration?

**Code**

This is paren class for all cards:

```
public abstract class CardStackView extends RelativeLayout {

protected CardStackListener cardStackListener;

public CardStackView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CardStackView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CardStackView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public void setCardStackListener(CardStackListener cardStackListener) {
    this.cardStackListener = cardStackListener;
    cardStackListener.onCreated(this);
}

protected interface CardStackListener {
    void onCreated(CardStackView view);

    void onRemove();

    void onAdd();
}

public abstract void setShade(float value);

public abstract void enable();

public abstract void disable();
```

}

And this is class of card holder which is responsible for cards swiching:

```
public class CardStackFragmentView extends FrameLayout {

private static final int MARGIN = 10;
private static final float SCALE = .1f;
private static final float ALPHA = .1f;

private List<CardStackView> totalCards = new LinkedList<>();
private List<CardStackView> cards = new LinkedList<>();
private Handler cardHandler = new Handler();

public CardStackFragmentView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "CardStackFragmentView");
}

public CardStackFragmentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "CardStackFragmentView");
}

/**
 * Adds cards from params to this card holder
 * and adds proper sizes and shade to be viewed like a card stack
 * @param cardStackViews cards for this card holder
 */
public void addCards(CardStackView... cardStackViews) {
    totalCards.addAll(Arrays.asList(cardStackViews));
    cards.addAll(Arrays.asList(cardStackViews));
    for (int i = cards.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        CardStackView card = cards.get(i);
        int offset = i;
        if (i == 0) {
            card.enable();
        } else {
            card.disable();
        }
        card.setCardStackListener(new CardStackView.CardStackListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCreated(CardStackView view) {
                view.animate()
                        .scaleX(1 - SCALE * offset)
                        .translationY(-MARGIN * offset);
                view.setShade(ALPHA * offset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRemove() {
                removeFromTop();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdd() {
                addCardToTop();
            }

        });
    }

    //I thought may be if i ll add cards in different threads it solves the problem

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        int tmp = i;
        cardHandler.postDelayed(() -> addView(cards.get((cards.size() - 1 - tmp))), i * 20);
    }
}


/**
 * Adds card on top of stack and reanimates all cards in stack
 */
public void addCardToTop() {
    CardStackView fragment = totalCards.get(totalCards.size() - (cards.size() + 1));
    fragment.animate().translationY(-(fragment.getHeight() + 30));
    cards.add(0, fragment);
    fragment.enable();
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        CardStackView card = cards.get(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            card.enable();
        } else {
            card.disable();
        }
        card.animate()
                .scaleX(1 - SCALE * i)
                .translationY(-MARGIN * i);
        card.setShade(ALPHA * i);
    }
}

public void removeFromTop() {
    Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "removeFromTop");
    CardStackView fragment = cards.get(0);
    fragment.animate().translationY(fragment.getHeight() + 30);
    fragment.disable();
    cards.remove(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        CardStackView card = cards.get(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            card.enable();
        } else {
            card.disable();
        }
        card.animate()
                .scaleX(1 - SCALE * i)
                .translationY(-MARGIN * i);
        card.setShade(ALPHA * i);
    }
}
```

}

This is onClick method to start animation:

```
@OnClick(R.id.tv_login_register)
public void createAccountClicked(View view) {
    LoginActivity loginActivity = ((LoginActivity) getContext());
    RegisterCard registerCard = new RegisterCard(loginActivity);
    loginActivity.hideMenu();
    view.setEnabled(false);
    startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(loginActivity, R.anim.move_out));
    new Handler().postDelayed(
            () -> {
                loginActivity.getCardsRelativeLayout().removeView(LoginCard.this);
                loginActivity.getCardsRelativeLayout().addView(registerCard);
                registerCard.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(loginActivity, R.anim.move_in));
            },
            400);
}
```

Thanks for your time. I hope this help you to help me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not in my custom card stack view, but in activity that contained this view (animation was skipping because there was huge freeze). It was too heavy and with big depth of layouts. So i just light up layout of activity and lags and freezes are gone =) So here is conclusion : **Make your xml layouts as light as possible**. This was simple answer for my complicated problem.